# Update Pyinstaller App with change in code

Tags: pyinstaller

I am a developer who is using python. All my code runs as a pyinstaller - made app.

Can any of you tell me how to update the app when the code is changed without having to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I use [EMCO MSI Package Builder](https://emcosoftware.com/msi-package-builder) to pack my files into MSI package. When I need to update my application I update the MSI with new files, change its product code, version (without changing upgrade code) inside of EMCO software, and build new MSI. After that I update MSI in SCCM (or it's possible to use group policies) and wait when users get it on their PCs.

Comment: Any way to do this in pyinstaller? Cause I don't really use MSI...